# PPTP connection permanently grayed out, defunct, but reported as "connected"

Tags: windows-8, vpn, pptp

A PPTP connection in my laptop got stuck in strange way:

- *Network Connections* window indicates it is connected:
  [image]
- It is visible in *Networks* panel with `Connect` button permanently grayed out. `Disconnect` button is never shown:
  [image]
- From the command line it appears as **connected** and **non-existant** (weird, uh?):
  [image]
- Immediately after the computer boots up, the connection is connected (although no other connections are connected yet) and therefore undeletable:
  [image]
- `rasdial.exe <connection name> /DISCONNECT`
  does not do anything (exactly the same output as with `rasdial` alone above).
- No resources in the VPN network are actually reachable (e.g. by pinging IP addresses etc.)
- This state persits computer restart.
- No restore point is available to potentially fix this via System Restore.
- It worked stable for couple of years, no configuration changes were made.
- Remote endpoint is OK, no changes were made.

**Please how can I recover this PPTP connection?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some 10 days, it suddenly started working again. The only related thing I observed was the upgrade of ESET SmartSecurity suite from major version 8.X to 9.X. PPTP started working about at the moment of the upgrade, ± some minutes... I did not spot it immediately.

For me, the most probable answer is this was caused by recent build of PC protection software which updates itself silently on background from time to time. (I do NOT mean database of virus definitions but executable binaries.)